# Cannot find paymentsheet in scope

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, stripe-payments

I am using this tutorial to connect my app with stripe via firebase -

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet&uikit-swiftui=swiftui

I could not find paymentsheet. Why does it say so, and how to sort-it-out ? I simplly want to connect stripe to my app using firebase. What is paymentsheet. Do I have to write some sort of sheet? what should be other code associated with it ? I have attached the screenshot of the error as well as written in it bold letters.

Here is the screenshot of the error: -

[image]

Now, my viewcontroller is :-

```
   import Stripe
   import SwiftUI

   class MyBackendModel: ObservableObject {
 let backendCheckoutUrl = URL(string: "Your backend endpoint")! // Your backend endpoint
 @Published var paymentSheet: PaymentSheet?//**Cannot find type 'PaymentSheet' in scope**
 @Published var paymentResult: PaymentSheetResult?//**Cannot find type 'PaymentSheet' in scope**

   init() {
   STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey = 

"pk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2tTT1SxPxRBzParFfjm6s0aXD0F5dYLeOSVCKtiZ4lq0TGwJxPhHpsq6Hga7I0QzRWisPYMdj00bDxAMTKf"

 }

    func preparePaymentSheet() {
  // MARK: Fetch the PaymentIntent and Customer information from the backend
   var request = URLRequest(url: backendCheckoutUrl)
   request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
  guard let data = data,
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
        let customerId = json["customer"] as? String,
        let customerEphemeralKeySecret = json["ephemeralKey"] as? String,
        let paymentIntentClientSecret = json["paymentIntent"] as? String,
        let self = self else {
        // Handle error
        return
      }

  // MARK: Create a PaymentSheet instance
  var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
  configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Example, Inc."
  configuration.customer = .init(id: customerId, ephemeralKeySecret: customerEphemeralKeySecret)

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret, configuration: configuration)
    }
    })
    task.resume()
  }

     func onPaymentCompletion(result: PaymentSheetResult) {
    self.paymentResult = result
   }
  }

 struct CheckoutView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model = MyBackendModel()

   var body: some View {
    VStack {
    if let paymentSheet = model.paymentSheet {
    PaymentSheet.PaymentButton(
      paymentSheet: paymentSheet,
      onCompletion: model.onPaymentCompletion
        ) {
        Text("Buy")
        }
        } else {
        Text("Loading…")
       }
      if let result = model.paymentResult {
       switch result {
      case .completed:
        Text("Payment complete")
       case .failed(let error):
        Text("Payment failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       case .canceled:
      Text("Payment canceled.")
      }
      }
      }.onAppear { model.preparePaymentSheet() }
     }
    }
```

Please assist me. I have been trying so long to connect my app to stripe, but unsuccessfull. I simply want my customer id. to show on stripe dashboard and other information also.

Comment: Clean your build folder and exit Xcode. You might want to delete Derived data too. Then open your project again and the error should be gone.

Comment: @Tadreik - no, it not gone

Comment: I had this issue in Xcode 13RC (not with Stripe, but with other packages). I did all of the above, removed and added the package as well as restarted. It finally started working again, but I am not sure what did it. It wasn't obvious at the time. Keep trying. Check your build settings as well.

Comment: The error with PaymentSheet is simply because you have a problem integrating Stripe SDK. You would want to debug it first. Have you completed the steps in here? https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet#setup-client-side

The tools used to integrate (CocoaPods vs Carthage vs SPM) are very different and the community only can help after knowing which is used.

Comment: @orakaro - I am using cocoapods

Comment: I am getting that error tried a lot but could not succeed yet. I am using the Stripe Package using Apple Package Manager

Answer (score 2):

PaymentSheet was added in the Stripe version 21.5.0. And if you are using a Stripe version below this, this error will come. This issue can be resolved by giving a higher deployment target and installing the pod again.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/releases

Answer (score 2):

If we are freshly installing the Stripe(Latest version 23.0) framework via Cocoapods, and trying to access Paymentsheet module it will through an error "Cannot find type PaymentSheet in scope".

In order to fix this add an additional POD called "StripePaymentSheet" in the pod file and do Pod Install via terminal.
And Inorder to use Paymentsheet, Import "StripePaymentSheet" module.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

import StripePaymentSheet

will solve the problem

Comment: No such module 'StripePaymentSheet'

Comment: First you need to add it's plugins than you need to import it in your file where you use paymentSheet

Answer (score 0):

In your Podfile put `pod 'StripePaymentSheet'`
instead `pod 'Stripe'`

and later in your file `import StripePaymentSheet`